# ¿Cómo convertir una columna a fecha en un determinado formato?

Tags: r, date

Tengo una matriz en R, con datos de twitter, y una de las columnas posee este formato de fecha `"Sun Jun 07 15:26:57 +0000 2015"` leído como texto. Cómo podría leer esa columna en formato de fecha en R? Ya probé varias fórmulas pero en todas me sale NA.

Comment: muestra que has intentado para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este link [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada no se lo tome a mal. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas probable es que obtengas NA por el idioma de las fechas que tienes predefinido

```
#usa para cambiar el idioma de las fechas a ingles
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
```

ahora puedes usar

```
#Para dar formato de fecha
as.Date("Sun Jun 07 15:26:57 +0000 2015",format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
#A toda la columna, eso si tienes un data frame
datos$columna<-as.Date(datos$columna,format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

Con [`as.Date()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.Date.html) puedes establecer el formato de entrada. Para tu ejemplo éste  sería: `"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y"`, es decir el nombre reducido del día de la semana, el nombre reducido del mes, el día, hora, minuto, segundo, la zona horaria y el año. Es decir la conversión podrías hacerla así:

```
as.Date("Sun Jun 07 15:26:57 +0000 2015",
        format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
```

Nota: el detalle de los formatos puedes consultarlo en la ayuda de la rutina [`strptime()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html)

Sin embargo, hay un problema adicional: la localización de la cadena. Por el texto `Sun` nos podemos dar cuenta que está en inglés, sin embargo, es posible que estemos procesando la cadena en un ambiente dónde la localización es en español, por lo que la conversión, no funcionaría, ya que el formato, si bien adecuado, asume la localización de nuestra sesión y no la de los datos. Esto se puede verificar fácilmente si reemplazamos **`Sun`** por **`Dom`**, es decir "Sunday" por "Domingo" y probamos hacer la conversión . Para solucionar esto es necesario modificar la localización actual de la sesión de la siguiente forma:

```
# Obtenemos y guardamos la localización actual
locale <- Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_TIME")

# configuramos la localización adecuada (en este caso inglés)
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")

# Ahora si hacemos la conversión
as.Date("Sun Jun 07 15:26:57 2015", format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")

# Restauramos la localización inicial
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", locale)
```

Sino, una alternativa es usar el paquete [`lubridate`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html) que permite configurar la localización en la misma conversión:

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time("Sun Jun 07 15:26:57 +0000 2015", "a b d H:M:S z Y", locale = "English")
```